# Python Function inputs

Tags: python

I am trying to teach myself Python on code academy and have written the following basic code, which is not working as whatever the input the outcome is `'Please Enter a Valid Number'` and I get a message saying `"Oops, try again! Make sure area_of_circle takes exactly one input (radius)."`

```
import math

radius = raw_input("Enter the radius of your circle")

def area_of_circle(radius):
    if type(radius) == int:
        return math.pi() * radius**2
    elif type(radius) == float:
        return math.pi() * radius**2
    else:
        return "'Please enter a valid number'"

print "Your Circle area is " + area_of_circle(radius) + " units squared"
```

The original assignment is:

> Write a function called `area_of_circle` that takes `radius` as input and returns the area of a circle. The area of a circle is equal to pi times the radius squared. (Use the math.pi in order to represent Pi.)

Comment: Don't use `type(variablename) == sometype`. At best, use `isinstance(variablename, sometype)`. Or just don't test at all, assume it's a valid type, that's more pythonic. Catch the exception if need be, but don't test for specific types.

Comment: Also note, `math.pi` is a number, not a function, so you'll need to change `math.pi()` to `math.pi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Errors in your program:

1. `raw_input()` returns a string, you've to convert to a `float` or `int` first.
2. Type checking is a bad idea in python
3. `math.pi()` is not a function just use `math.pi`

Use [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) to convert the string into a number:

```
import math
radius = raw_input("Enter the radius of your circle: ")
def area_of_circle(radius):
    try :
        f = float(radius) #if this conversion fails then the `except` block will handle it
        return math.pi * f**2   #use just math.pi
    except ValueError:
        return "'Please enter a valid number'"

print "Your Circle area is {0} units squared".format(area_of_circle(radius))
```

Comment: Thankyou I am only a day into python so still finding my legs! ;)

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input()` *always* returns a `str`. You need to pass it to another type's constructor in order to convert it.

```
radius_val = float(radius)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can type cast it while reading the input:

`radius = float(raw_input("Enter the radius of your circle"))`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you want different paths for if the input is a int or float (which doesn't make much sense)

```
if type(radius) == int:
        return math.pi() * radius**2
elif type(radius) == float:
```

As the interpretation of `raw_input()`'s string could be either int or float you should evaluate it like so:

```
import ast
radius = ast.literl_eval(raw_input("Enter the radius of your circle"))
```

This way you can avoid trying to check if it is a float or int etc...

```
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(raw_input("Number: ")))
Number: 2.5
<type 'float'>
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(raw_input("Number: ")))
Number: 5
<type 'int'>
```